# Call form controls' properties in a function

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a function that receives forms as an input. I need to use controls' properties of the passed form. For example:

```
Private Sub Drawing(ByVal frm As Form)

    X = frm.a.Left + frm.a.Width

End Sub
```

Visual basic doesn't accept this method that I use. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be like this :

```
Private Sub Drawing(ByVal frm As Form)

    Dim i As Control()
    i = frm.Controls.Find("a", True)

    if i.Length <> 0 Then
        X = i(0).Left + i(0).Right
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `frm.a.*` also works _if_ the control is non-dynamic and has a member variable accessible by other forms. Also, `i` is an array, it has no `Left` property. I think what you meant was `i(0).Left`.

Comment: oops.. just forgot to type the index there... thanks @Vincent

Answer (score 1):

*"Visual Basic doesn't accept this method that I use"* is a **very** vague description of your problem. You should be specific with what errors you get and what you want the result to be, because we are not mindreaders and can therefore not tell what the problem is unless we get clear information.

But if you're trying to change a control's/form's X-position you have to change the entire `Location` property.

Change the current form's X-position:

```
Me.Location = New Point(frm.a.Left + frm.a.Width, Me.Location.Y)
```

Change a control's X-position (where `YourControl` is the name of the control you want to move):

```
YourControl.Location = New Point(frm.a.Left + frm.a.Width, YourControl.Location.Y)
```